# Python matcher not matching

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a very simple regex script in python that matches all lowercase characters, but the matcher is returning "None"

Here's my code:

```
p = re.compile('[a-z]+')
print(p.match('This is a test'))
p
```

Comment: wrong test case , should be `thisisatest` there are spaces and `T`

Comment: Spaces are not lowercase letters

Comment: I was just trying to find the first time the match apeared, so it should return 'his'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong method, `match` doesn't search the whole string, it only checks if the string matches starting from the beginning of the string.

Take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

the `search` function might do it though!

```
p = re.compile('[a-z]+')
s = p.search('This is a test')
print(s.group(0))
```

Comment: This does exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2):

`match` starts matching at the beginning of a string. Your string starts with a capital letter, so it doesn't match it and gives up.

Perhaps you wanted `findall`?

```
>>> p = re.compile('[a-z]+')
>>> print(p.findall('This is a test'))
['his', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Comment: I have got to answer these questions faster, I'm always half way through typing mine when someone answers :P